# Pymodbus: After StopServer -> StartSerialServer doesn't work (could not open port: PermissionError)

Tags: python, multithreading, pyserial, pymodbus

**Versions:** Python: 3.9 | Pymodbus: 2.5.1

**Pymodbus Specific:** Server: rtu - sync/async | Client: rtu - sync/async

**Description:**

In my application I want to start a SerialServer, which can be read by a client connected over RTU. After the client has read the values I want to stop the server. At this point the user should be able to change some values himself and start the SerialServer again.
Exactly the second start of the SerialServer doesn't work, because the server can't open the port.

```
from pymodbus.version import version
from pymodbus.server.asynchronous import StartSerialServer, StopServer
from pymodbus.device import ModbusDeviceIdentification
from pymodbus.datastore import ModbusSparseDataBlock
from pymodbus.datastore import ModbusSlaveContext, ModbusServerContext
from pymodbus.transaction import ModbusRtuFramer

import time
import sys
import threading
from qtpy import QtWidgets

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

def modbus_server_start():
    print("Modbus-Server start:")

    class CustomDataBlock(ModbusSparseDataBlock):
        def setValues(self, address, value):
            super(CustomDataBlock, self).setValues(0, value_1)
            super(CustomDataBlock, self).setValues(1, 11)
            super(CustomDataBlock, self).setValues(2, 12)

    block = CustomDataBlock({0: [0] * 100})
    store = ModbusSlaveContext(hr=block)
    context = ModbusServerContext(slaves=store)

    identity = ModbusDeviceIdentification()
    identity.VendorName = 'pymodbus'
    identity.ProductCode = 'PM'
    identity.VendorUrl = 'http://github.com/riptideio/pymodbus/'
    identity.ProductName = 'pymodbus Server'
    identity.ModelName = 'pymodbus Server'
    identity.MajorMinorRevision = version.short()

    StartSerialServer(context, framer=ModbusRtuFramer, identity=identity, port='COM6', timeout=0.05, baudrate=19200)

def server_start():
    print("Start an async server.")
    t = threading.Thread(target=modbus_server_start)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

def modbus_server_stop():
    stopthread = threading.Thread(target=stop)
    stopthread.daemon = True
    stopthread.start()
    print("Server was stopped.")

def stop():
    print("Process will be down.")
    StopServer()  # Stop server.
    sys.exit(0)  # Kill the server code.

window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
window.setWindowTitle("StartSerialServer")
window.setGeometry(500, 500, 400, 125)

button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(window)
button.setText("Start")
button.setGeometry(0, 0, 60, 30)
button.show()
button.clicked.connect(server_start)

button2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(window)
button2.setText("Stop")
button2.setGeometry(100, 0, 60, 30)
button2.show()
button2.clicked.connect(modbus_server_stop)

combobox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(window)
combobox.setGeometry(50, 40, 60, 30)
combobox.addItem("")
combobox.addItem("")
combobox.addItem("")
combobox.addItem("")
combobox.addItem("")
combobox.setItemText(0, "0")
combobox.setItemText(1, "10")
combobox.setItemText(2, "20")
combobox.setItemText(3, "30")
combobox.setItemText(4, "40")
combobox.show()
global value_1
value_1 = combobox.currentText()

window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Error code:

```
Start an async server.
Modbus-Server start:
Process will be down.
Server was stopped.

Exception in thread Thread-4:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python32\lib\threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
Start an async server.
Modbus-Server start:
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python32\lib\threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Python32\Projekte\Pymodbus-Test\github_issue.py", line 36, in modbus_server_start
    StartSerialServer(context, framer=ModbusRtuFramer, identity=identity, port='COM6', timeout=0.05, baudrate=19200)
  File "C:\Python32\Projekte\Pymodbus-Test\venv\lib\site-packages\pymodbus\server\asynchronous.py", line 340, in StartSerialServer
    SerialPort(protocol, port, reactor, baudrate=baudrate, parity=parity,
  File "C:\Python32\Projekte\Pymodbus-Test\venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\_win32serialport.py", line 44, in __init__
    self._serial = self._serialFactory(
  File "C:\Python32\Projekte\Pymodbus-Test\venv\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 33, in __init__
    super(Serial, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python32\Projekte\Pymodbus-Test\venv\lib\site-packages\serial\serialutil.py", line 244, in __init__
    self.open()
  File "C:\Python32\Projekte\Pymodbus-Test\venv\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 64, in open
    raise SerialException("could not open port {!r}: {!r}".format(self.portstr, ctypes.WinError()))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port 'COM6': PermissionError(13, 'Zugriff verweigert', None, 5)
```

I thought about closing and reopen the server but this also doesn't work.

Maybe somebody could help me to fix the problem. :)